# How to have Subclasses serialize parent value differently using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Say I have the following class structure

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    string maker;
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    bool automatic;
}

class Motorcycle : Vehicle
{
    string style;
}

class Bicycle : Vehicle
{
    // no extra attributes
}
```

and want to serialize/deserialize into this form:

```
<vehicles>
    <car maker="BMW">
        <automatic>false</automatic>
    </car>
    <motorcycle>
        <maker>Harley Davidson</maker>
        <style>Cruiser</style>
    </motorcycle>
    <bicycle>Huffy</bicycle>
</vehicles>
```

Is there a way to tell the XML serializer how `maker` should be serialized in each case, or do I need to move the `maker` variable down into its subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. I can make maker an abstract string and implement it with a different backing variable for each, then tag the backing variable as needed.